# Cox PH model with XGBoost, how to get survival time?

Tags: python, xgboost, survival-analysis, non-linear-regression, cox-regression

```
clf = XGBRegressor(objective='survival:cox', min_child_weight=4, gamma=0.50,
                   subsample=0.6, eta=1, max_depth=10, booster='gblinear', reg_lambda = 2)
```

When I use this objective, I only get the hazard ratio (HR) ( i.e., as HR = exp(marginal_prediction) in the proportional hazard function h(t) = h0(t) * HR). I would like to get the whole survival time prediction. How could I achieve so through XGBoost ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

> How could I achieve so through XGBoost ?

If you are ok with a departure from proportional hazards assumption, try the Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) model (see [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/aft_survival_analysis.html), and [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04920)). Instead of modeling `HR,` AFT models try predicting log of survival time directly.

If you want to stick to proportional hazards, looks like there is a way to estimate $h_0(t)$, at least in R - so you may have to replicate it in python (see [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65266/how-do-i-predict-survival-curves-using-xgboost) stack overflow answer).